# Is there any tutor like the 'vimtutor'?

Tags: linux, vim

I find that the `vimtutor` is very great, is there more command to teach you other things too? Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more specific? What other command do you want to learn. A focused, specific question would fetch quicker and accurate responses from the community.

Answer (score 3):

No. `$ vimtutor` teaches you the basics but there is no canonical/interactive tutorial beyond that.

But I tend to agree with Vim's author's point of view which is (as far as I understand it correctly) that one should grow his knowledge of his editor organically: do things how they come and ask yourself how you could do it faster or more efficiently and look for a way.

You can count on Google to point you to many "How I switched to Vim" blog posts, cheatsheets, screencasts and enlightening StackOverflow answers. But nothing as thorough as `$ vimtutor` I'm afraid.